# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.gamingwave.sprachassistent.text.sprechen(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I tried to make a voiceassistant. First it should get the voice input in the main class, and then do a voice output in the text class. But I got this error:

```
2023-02-01 20:24:12.776 11850-11850/de.gamingwave.sprachassistent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.gamingwave.sprachassistent, PID: 11850
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void de.gamingwave.sprachassistent.text.sprechen(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at de.gamingwave.sprachassistent.MainActivity$1.onResults(MainActivity.java:90)
        at android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$InternalListener$1.handleMessage(SpeechRecognizer.java:456)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2023-02-01 20:24:12.781 11850-11850/de.gamingwave.sprachassistent I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11850 SIG: 9
```

This is the MainActivity:

```
    package de.gamingwave.sprachassistent;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import de.gamingwave.sprachassistent.text;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

        private EditText txtRecognizedSpeech;
        private ImageButton btnSpeak;

        private static MainActivity instance;

        private Boolean isListening = false;
        private int RecordAudioRequestCode = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                txtRecognizedSpeech = findViewById(R.id.txtRecognizedSpeech);
                btnSpeak = findViewById(R.id.btnSpeech);
                speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
                final Intent speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "de-DE");

                speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

                        }

                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                                txtRecognizedSpeech.setHint("Listening...");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int error) {

                        }

                        //         ...
//        ....
//        ...
//        ...
                        @Override
                        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                                ArrayList<String> speechData = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                                txtRecognizedSpeech.setText(speechData.get(0));
                                String result = speechData.get(0);
                                if(result.contains("hallo")){
                                        text.getInstance().sprechen("Hallo, wie gehts?");
                                }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                        }

                });


                btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (isListening.equals(true)){
                                        speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                                        isListening = false;
                                }
                                else if (isListening.equals(false)){
                                        speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
                                        isListening = true;
                                }
                        }
                });

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                if (requestCode == RecordAudioRequestCode && grantResults.length > 0 ){
                        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

        public static MainActivity getInstance() {
                return instance;
        }
}

                    @Override
                    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                    }

            });


            btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (isListening.equals(true)){
                                    speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                                    isListening = false;
                            }
                            else if (isListening.equals(false)){
                                    speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
                                    isListening = true;
                            }
                    }
            });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == RecordAudioRequestCode && grantResults.length > 0 ){
                    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
            return instance;
    }
}
```

`

This is text.java

```
package de.gamingwave.sprachassistent;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

import java.util.Locale;

public class text implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    TextToSpeech tts;
    private static text instance;

    public void onInit(int status) {
        instance = this;
        tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.getInstance(), this);
        tts.setSpeechRate(1.0F);
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMANY);

                }
    }

    public void sprechen(String text){
        tts.speak("Hallo, wie geht es dir?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    public static text getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Do you know, what's the problem?

I tried to make a speech to text application looking for signal words. Then the app has to answer via text to speech. But it crashes when is should say something.

Comment: Has you called ```text.onInit()``` to initialize your ```text```'s ```instance```?